# WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 integration with another Billing Engine

Tags: wso2, stripe-payments, wso2-api-manager, billing

I'm trying to integrate a billing engine with WSO2. But there's no documentation on the WSO2 doc (other than Stripe).

How can I configure another billing engine?

Comment: You can extend the monetization interface and integrate another billing engine. See - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-monetization/monetizing-an-api/#monetize-an-api

Comment: Isn't there another way?  In this way, I should buy a license. I also have no idea how to extend that file.

Comment: what about this:  https://github.com/ruks/wso2-am-billing-engine

Comment: Yes, that is a good example.